# "Cannot resolve symbol" al importar (en AndroidStudio IDE)

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, java-import

Estoy trabajando en AndroidStudio. Agregué una carpeta (aplib) a mi proyecto principal, como se puede ver en la imagen.

[image: carpeta aplib agregada al proyecto]

Luego, quise importar los datos de aplib/src/main/java/nl/uu/cs/aplib/AplibEDSL.java en el archivo de prueba HelloArActivityTest.java.

[image: Ruta de HelloArActivityTest.java]

En HelloArActivityTest.java, utilicé *import static aplib.src.main.java.nl.uu.cs.aplib.AplibEDSL.*;* para importarlo, y debería funcionar bien, porque ha funcionado bien otras veces en otros proyectos, usado por otras personas. Pero esta es la primera vez que lo pruebo. Se detecta un error y AndroidStudio muestra el mensaje *Cannot resolve symbol 'AplibEDSL'*.

[image: Error al importar los datos]

Llevo mucho tiempo buscando pero no encuentro la solución. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

No puede importar una clase que esté en recursos o en algún otro lugar.

Si desea usar / importar una clase, necesita que esté dentro de "**java**" y entre los paquetes de su aplicación, o necesita que su JAR se importe como dependencia para su aplicación.

"**res**" es para imágenes, properties u otros recursos, no para archivos java.

Todas las clases que desee usar deben estar en `src\androidTest\java\`. Puede tener varios paquetes aquí, pero deben estar aquí.

Comment: Gracias por la información. Ahora he cambiado la ubicación de la carpeta _aplib_ a `src\androidTest\java\aplib`. 

Sin embargo, el error persiste. Imagino que el import sería igual que antes, verdad?

Comment: No del todo, y creo que aún necesita arreglar algunas carpetas. en la imagen tienes "aplib\src\main.java\nl.uu.cs.aplib\AplibEDSL.java" pero "applib\src\main.java" no es parte del paquete, es la configuración de otro diferente proyecto, si desea incorporarlo a su proyecto, debe importar solo "nl\uu\cs\aplib\AplibEDSL.java" en su carpeta "java", de lo que su importación sería "nl.uu.cs.aplib .AplibEDSL"

Comment: @BorjaDavó src\androidTest\java\  no es correcto, este directorio es para pruebas instrumentadas.

Comment: Gracias a los dos por la información. Y muchas gracias @res por la ayuda, ese era la forma de solucionarlo que estaba buscando. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

> Agregué una carpeta (aplib) a mi proyecto principal

La forma de agregar una biblioteca es simplemente agregar el .jar dentro del directorio `/lib`.

Si lo que tienes es el código de la biblioteca, debes agregarlo dentro de :

```
src/main/java/<paquete de aplicación>/
```

---

Descarga la biblioteca desde: https://ibsensoftware.com/download.html